# PHP CSV Export With MetaData

Tags: php, csv

I have a basic order system that I've built in PHP. Each product can have an unlimited number of metadata entries (containing information for that product). I want to build a CSV export that will include each metadata option as a column in the export file. The export should only contain the metadata for the products in the order.

For example, if I have the following array:

```
order = array(
    'Product1' => array(
        'name' => 'TShirt',
        'MetaData' => array(
            '1' => array(
                'key' => 'size',
                'value' => 'm'
            )
     ),
    'Product2' => array(
        'name' => 'Backpack',
        'MetaData' => array(
            '1' => array(
                'key' => 'waist',
                'value' => '50 cm'
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'key' => 'height',
                'value' => '150 cm'
            )
            '3' => array(
                'key' => 'chest',
                'value' => '25 cm'
            )
     ),
)
```

I would like the CSV to look like:

```
(header row): product / size / waist / height / chest
(data row):   t-shirt / m / NULL / NULL / NULL
(data row):   backpack / NULL / 50 cm / 150 cm / 25 cm
```

I know I can hardcode this, but I want it to be scalable. I know this will need to be done in 2 steps - 1) build the columns by iterating through each product and each product's meta, 2) add a row entry for each product - but I can't exactly nail down how to do it. The problem I'm running in to is knowing which column I'm inserting data into. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it strictly required that the data be exported to CSV? Why not something simple that maintains the existing hierarchy like JSON? `json_encode($order);` done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. Hope it gives you a starting point.

```
<?php

// Your original array (I've made a few corrections)

$order = array(
    'Product1' => array(
        'name' => 'TShirt',
        'MetaData' => array(
            '1' => array(
                'key' => 'size',
                'value' => 'm'
            )
        )
    ),
    'Product2' => array(
        'name' => 'Backpack',
        'MetaData' => array(
            '1' => array(
                'key' => 'waist',
                'value' => '50 cm'
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'key' => 'height',
                'value' => '150 cm'
            ), 
            '3' => array(
                'key' => 'chest',
                'value' => '25 cm'
            )
        )
    ),
);

// Declare header array to receive all keys from metadata
$header = array();

// Sweep metadata portion of array to retrieve keys
foreach ($order as $product) {
    foreach ($product['MetaData'] as $metadata) {
        if (! in_array($metadata['key'], $header)) {
            $header[] = $metadata['key'];
        }
    }
}

// Declare content array
$content = array();

// Sweep array again to get the appropriate key/value matches
foreach ($order as $product) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = $product['name'];
    // Get metadata
    foreach ($header as $heading) {
        $added = false; // set a flag so if there are no matches, fill with "NULL" (below)
        foreach ($product['MetaData'] as $metadata) {
            if ($heading == $metadata['key']) { // if the heading matches the metadata key, we got a match
                $row[] = $metadata['value'];
                $added = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (! $added) {
            $row[] = 'NULL';
        }
    }

    // Add the row to the content array
    $content[] = $row;
}

// Put it all together
$csv = 'product / ' . implode(' / ', $header) . "\n";
foreach ($content as $row) {
    $csv .= implode(' / ', $row) . "\n";
}

echo "<pre>$csv</pre>";

?>
```

Good luck!